# Node.JS multiple new Class only last executed (http & socket.io-client)

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io

First sorry for my bad english.

I tried connect to server using http token authentication with socket.io as exchange data. When socket.io got an error then request token by http and try to connect again.

I put the connection function in the class then call it from main program. My problem is when I create multiple client why only last work, here my code

**call the class**

```
const SocketHttpClient = require('./class/socket-http-client')

let ioClient_1 = new SocketHttpClient('localhost', 3001, 'admin', 'admin', '/login')
let ioClient_2 = new SocketHttpClient('localhost', 3002, 'admin', 'admin', '/login')
let ioClient_3 = new SocketHttpClient('localhost', 3003, 'admin', 'admin', '/login')
```

**connection class**

```
// =================================================================================================
// INCLUDE LIBRARY
// =================================================================================================
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client')
const http = require('http')
const cookie = require('cookie')

const log = require('./log-custom')


// =================================================================================================
// VARIABLE
// =================================================================================================
let data
let httpOption

ioOption = {
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        Cookie: 'hello=world'
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = class Socket {
  constructor(ioHostname, ioPort, httpUsername, httpPassword, loginPath) {  
    data = {
      username: httpUsername,
      password: httpPassword
    }

    data = JSON.stringify(data)

    httpOption = {
      hostname: ioHostname,
      port: ioPort,
      path: loginPath,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
      }
    }

    log(`Connecting to "${httpOption.hostname}:${httpOption.port}"`)
    this.io = ioClient(`http://${httpOption.hostname}:${httpOption.port}`, ioOption)

    this.io.on('connect', () => {
      log(`Connected to socket "${httpOption.hostname}:${httpOption.port}"`)
    })
    this.io.on('disconnect', () => {
      log(`Disconnected to socket "${httpOption.hostname}:${httpOption.port}"`)
      log('Reconnecting...')
    })
    this.io.on('error', () => {
      console.log(`error: ${httpOption.hostname}:${httpOption.port}`)
      // When error then try to reconnect...
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.io.disconnect()
        this.io.close()
        this.req = http.request(httpOption, res => {
          this.c = cookie.parse(res.headers['set-cookie'][0])
          ioOption.transportOptions.polling.extraHeaders.Cookie = `sid=${this.c.sid}`
          this.io.io.opts.query = ioOption
        })

        this.req.write(data)
        this.req.end()

        this.req.on('error', err => {
          
        })

        // delay to reconnect
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.io.connect()
        }, 1000)
      }, 1000)
    })

  }

}
```

**the result:**

ioClient_1 => not working

ioClient_2 => not working

ioClient_3 => working fine as expected

Where I doing wrong here? Need advice from you guys. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: each of your clients are using a diff port to socket.io server, perhaps 3003 is the actual only working port, are you running multiple server instances?

Comment: also note that `data`, `httpOption` and (wheres var, let, const) `ioOption` vars are shared between all client instances

Comment: Ok let me try..

Comment: you dont need to write you own reconnection code either, its built-in https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Manager

Comment: Hi Lawrence Cherone, Thank you for the answer "also note that data, httpOption and (wheres var, let, const) ioOption vars are shared between all client instances" it works like a charm. and thank you for the advice about reconnection 